# svn merge failure: connection forcibly closed by remote host

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, wireshark, vpn

While working from home over our company VPN and trying to do a catch-up merge from trunk to a development branch, my merge fails with the error

```
Error running context: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

The merge operation always starts and some files get merged, but then at a random time after the merge was started the merge failes with the above error.  This happens with either TortoiseSVN (1.12.0, Build 28572 - 64 Bit -dev, 2019/05/06 20:01:07) or the command line svn client (version 1.12.0 r1857323).

In my `C:\Users\bart\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\servers`, I have (excluding comments):

```
[groups]

[global]
http-timeout = 3600
```

which I think is OK.

Using WireShark, I have captured the traffic during the failing merge operation.  It can be found at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rsRgzQAikCWTHs80u_0_dYGs9jMrcG6b/view?usp=sharing  In that capture, I see a lot of TCP Out-Of-Order, Dup ACK, Spurious Retransmission packets, and near the end I see some TCP [RST] packets going from the server to the client, and then TCP [RST, ACK] packets going back from the client to the server, which is I assume the 'forcibly closing of the connection' as reported by subversion.

I am wondering whether this is a client-side or server-side problem.  Looking at my capture file, can anyone tell me what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: This has to be a problem with VPN. The client drops the connection unexpectedly. Server or client side timeout should not be relevant.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am using the Sophos SSL VPN Client 2.1 which according to its log file uses OpenVPN 2.3.8.  In that log file, I don't really see anything suspicious.  Also, when the merge fails, my VPN connection stays up and running (the Sophos SSL VPN Client icon stays green and does not change to red).